# Elasticsearch Nested Query using Java API and Rest API Query Have Different Response

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on Elasticsearch(7.1.1) nested queries using java API for nested mapping index I have on my local machine. I am getting a response that are not the same as the rest api query I have.

I have a mapping that specify it is nested and it works fine when I tested it on kibana.

Here is an example query using Rest api.

```
GET my-index/_search
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "nested":{
                  "path":"xx.yy.",
                  "query":{
                     "bool":{
                        "must":[
                           {
                              "match":{
                                 "xx.yy.NAME":"cc"
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "match":{
                                 "xx.yy..VALUE":"ss"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "nested":{
                  "path":"xx.yy",
                  "query":{
                     "bool":{
                        "must":[
                           {
                              "match":{
                                 "xx.yy.NAME":"ff"
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "match":{
                                 "xx.yy.VALUE":"ee"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "nested":{
                  "path":"xx.yy",
                  "query":{
                     "bool":{
                        "must":[
                           {
                              "match":{
                                 "xx.yy.NAME":"kk"
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "match":{
                                 "xx.yy.VALUE":"gg"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

And here is an equivalent java code I come up with.

```
searchSourceBuilder.query( QueryBuilders.boolQuery ()
    .must(QueryBuilders.nestedQuery( path,  matchQuery ( fNameOne, fValueOne ),ScoreMode.Avg )).minimumShouldMatch ( 1 )
    .must(QueryBuilders.nestedQuery( path,  matchQuery ( fNameTwo, fValueTwo ),ScoreMode.Avg )).minimumShouldMatch ( 1 )
    .must(QueryBuilders.nestedQuery (path,  matchQuery ( fNameThree, fValueThree ),ScoreMode.Avg )).minimumShouldMatch(1));
```

Can anyone point me where I made a mistake or give me direction how to tackle this problem? Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your java code doesn't correspond to your DSL. In the latter, you have two must clauses in each nested query, whereas in your Java code only a single must clause per nested query. I would start there.

Comment: Val thanks for your reply. Do you have any suggestions how to change it?